# Driving a PWM controller with an SMPS - Does my motor like it?

Tags: pwm, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-motor, motor-controller

SMPS Power supply: [MP 3800](https://www.jaycar.com.au/compact-switchmode-laboratory-power-supply/p/MP3800)

I have a 12V brushed DC motor hooked up to a [PWM controller](https://www.jaycar.com.au/12vdc-8a-dimmer-motor-speed-controller/p/MP3209). When I run the motor (all works as it should) however there is a lot of crackling noise coming from the PSU.

Note: Snubber diode (or 'Flyback' diode) added due to PWM Controller manual recommendation.

Considering the PSU has its own PWM...am I creating dirty power by chopping the signal once again with my PWM controller?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxppNc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You aren't doing anything terribly wrong, but your design really needs some capacitors between the PSU and the PWM controller.

Comment: @hekete - How many caps should I shunt and how best to calculate them? (Assuming electrolytic will be ok?)

Comment: How much current does the motor draw?

Comment: @BruceAbbott - 2-3A normal operation. 5A under stall conditions

Comment: There are too many unknowns to really make a best calculation. You can either scope it, or go with the usual method of trial and error. A 100nF ceramic is usually a good place to start for noise. Then maybe try 10,47,100uF electrolytics and see if it improves at all.